# importing cuml in a docker image

Tags: docker, nvidia-docker

I'm building a custom rapidsai docker image based on its devel image. Here is the docker file.

```
FROM rapidsai/rapidsai-dev:0.19-cuda11.0-devel-ubuntu18.04-py3.7

# Defining working directory and adding source code
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

RUN echo "Make sure cuml is installed:"
RUN python -c "import cuml"
```

But when I built it with this command,

```
nvidia-docker build . -t test
```

it returns an error saying:

```
Step 4/4 : RUN python -c "import cuml"
 ---> Running in 553d12bf7e68
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cuml'
```

It seems that it can't recognize cuml library which is already a part of the libraries of the base image. Why it can't import it?

Answer (score 1):

Just fixed it. This will work without any issue

```
FROM rapidsai/rapidsai-dev:0.19-cuda11.0-devel-ubuntu18.04-py3.7


# Defining working directory and adding source code
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

RUN echo "conda activate rapids" >> ~/.bashrc
SHELL ["/bin/bash", "--login", "-c"]
```

then install some libraries..and

```
RUN export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcuda.so.1:${LD_LIBRARY_PATH:+:${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}}
RUN export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/cuda-11.0/compat/libcuda.so.1:${LD_LIBRARY_PATH:+:${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}}

COPY test_cuml.py .

RUN echo "conda activate rapids" >> ~/.bashrc
SHELL ["/bin/bash", "--login", "-c"]
ENTRYPOINT ["/opt/conda/envs/rapids/bin/python", "test_cuml.py"]
```